# How to and is good practice to create generic Host class extension methods in ASPNETCORE 3?

Tags: c#, host, .net-core-3.0

In typical aspnet core application. 
As a example of Program.cs

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
      .Build(); 

   await host.RunAsync();
```

How we must declare if we wish to extend HostBuilder capablites with extension methods as when using "CreateDefaultBuilder()" with IWebHost in netcore <2.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create IHostBuilder extension method.

Begins creating a static class with static methods (public)
Import to the client that is going to use the method.

Declaration is as follows:

```
public static class MyHostHostBuilderExtension
    {
        public static IHostBuilder CreateMyBuilder(this IHostBuilder hostBuilder)
[...]
```

In the Program.cs use a HostBuilder() instance.

```
var host = new HostBuilder().CreateMyBuilder().Build();
```

Notice if you using Host static class. It can't be extended.